# JQGrid (searchOnEnter: true) Bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, jqgrid

When I declare **searchOnEnter: true** in my grid, it allows me to use the enter key while doing a search on my grid. Nevertheless, when I press the enter key to do the search, it doesn't filter the grid at all. When I repeat the same actions twice however, the filter works the second time around. I have no idea why this is happening. One thought is that it may be sending an empty string the first time around, even though I clearly enter search text, but again I'm not sure. Any help is appreciated.

-Adam

Comment: Can you please post your grid setup and any corresponding code? Otherwise, your problem will be difficult to solve...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem you need to patch the source code of jqGrid. You need to find the handler of keydown event (the function that runs when you press Enter button in search dialog). This code can be found by searching "searchOnEnter" in source file. The right fragment looks so:

```
    if (p.searchOnEnter || p.closeOnEscape) {
       $("#"+$.jgrid.jqID(IDs.themodal)).keydown(function (e) {
          var $target = $(e.target);
          if (p.searchOnEnter && e.which === 13 && // 13 === $.ui.keyCode.ENTER
             !$target.hasClass('add-group') && !$target.hasClass('add-rule') &&
             !$target.hasClass('delete-group') && !$target.hasClass('delete-rule') &&
             (!$target.hasClass("fm-button") || !$target.is("[id$=_query]"))) {
```

Here you should split the code line `$("#"+fid+"_search").focus().click();`
on the following two:

```
                $("#"+fid+"_search").focus();
                setTimeout(function(){
                   $("#"+fid+"_search").click();
                },0);
```

ending by the original code:

```
                return false;
          }
```

(see also [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/145e2caae027e2ba49f4b34b1a03caee57fdd3db))

Answer (score 0):

This caused due to bug in `grid.filter.js` of struts2-jquery-grid-plugin.